# How to 'Add Configuration' in Intelij for Dart

Tags: dart, intellij-idea, configuration

How to 'Add Configuration' in Intelij for Dart.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPxjk.png)

Answer (score 0):

Click **Add configuration** link and then choose the needed configuration ([Dart Command Line App](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-dart-command-line-application.html) or whatever configuration you need) from **Templates**. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration.html#create-permanent, https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/dart.html#dart_run_command_line_application